# Design fields mapping function on Salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

What are the common and good design patterns that users can design their own mappings?

For example, a user can define one field can map to another field.

`Custom.name` -> `Account.name`

`Custom.address` -> `User.street_address`

Where can I put/store this information in a user-friendly way for a user who doesn't know APEX too much?

With these features, I can remove the hard coded mapping part from the APEX backend code.

Thanks.

Comment: A system administrator, or any arbitrary user?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Custom Metadata Type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_overview.htm&type=0), which allows System Administrators to choose fields directly as lookup values, and you can access these in Apex Code, package them in packages, and migrate them via Change Sets. All of the information you'll need is the linked documentation, or you can view this directly in Help under "Custom Metadata Types."